# Submit button does not work in html5

Tags: html

I have the following submit button that does not take me to search.php. Please guide me what is wrong with it.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:80px;">
    <form class="form-signin" id="Form1" action="search.php" method="post"> 

    <div class=" col-xs-12" style="float:left;display:inline;">
      <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="city">City: </label>
        <input id="city">
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  type="submit">Search</button> 
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<button type="button" .... type="submit">Search</button>
```

You have defined `type` twice. Remove the one you don't want.